# asp-for in a .cshtml page is not validating against my model using asp helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Core v7 preview following along with BHRUGEN Patel's Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eru2emiqow0. At 2:04:41 he lays out how you can validate user fields against the database model using "asp" helpers before the page is submitted to the server. But in the case below, I cannot trigger the client-side error messages. I.e., I can't seem to trigger the asp-for helpers against my Category model and hence, the page is sent on to be rejected by the server validation routine. Here is the `Create.cshtml` file, the `Category.cs` class, and the database CREATE DDL:

*.cshtml file:*

```
@page
@model AbbyTrain.Pages.Categories.CreateModel
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
<form method="post">
    
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4"> 
        <div class="row pb-2"> 
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Create New Category</h2> 
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Category.Name"></label>        
            <input asp-for="Category.Name" class="form-control"/>       
            <span asp-validation-for="Category.Name" class="text-danger"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Category.DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input asp-for="Category.DisplayOrder" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Category.DisplayOrder" class="text-danger"></span>        
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="Category.DateCreated"></label> 
            <input readonly name="Category.DateCreated" class="form-control bg-info"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="Category.DateCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="bnt btn-primary" style="width: 150px;">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

*Category class:*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AbbyTrain.Models
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            ProductCategories = new HashSet<ProductCategories>();
        }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
        
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<ProductCategories> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DDL File to Create the category in SQL Server:

```
USE [AbbyTrain]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Category]    Script Date: 5/16/2022 5:18:25 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DisplayOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Category] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Category] ADD  DEFAULT (N'') FOR [Name]
GO
```

Per Farid's comment I am including the server side code:
Create.cshtml.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        await _db.Category.AddAsync(Category);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
    else

        return RedirectToPage("Create");
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Updated 2022-05-18 8:15 UTC

I hope this helps to "jog" someone's mind :)

So if I use the data annotation [Display(Name="Display1 Order")], this works. But if I use the [Required(ErrorMessage="Category Name is required")] this does not work. It seems like the model is totally disconnected from displaying error messages and does not display implicitly through the model or explicitly using data annotations.

Here is my Category.cs file with data annotations:

```
namespace AbbyTrain.Models
{
    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            ProductCategories = new HashSet<ProductCategories>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")] <--this does not work
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display Order is Required")] <--this does not work 
        [Display(Name="Display1 Order")] <--This works
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<ProductCategories> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there a bug in the Core code? I am using preview releases.

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#client-side-validation ?

Comment: SQL Server is not a relevant tag for this question as its quite clear the issue doesn't lie there.

Comment: Could you please include your `controller` or `backend details` code how are you saving into database?

Comment: I did read the docs on client-side validation from Microsoft and added a [Required] attributes to the name and display order fields even though it is superfluous.  I still can't validate these fields on the client side.

Comment: What validation message are you expecting for example? In addition could you please include `controller` code how you are doring `read-write` operation? So that we can easily simulate your issue.

Comment: Farid, it is a Post to the database to create a new Category using EF Core to Sql Server with a default ID field as the identity, Name and DisplayOrder fields that are null after hitting the submit button.  It is my understanding that the model using client side JS routines will display something like Name and DisplayOrder are required fields. Bootstrap then displays the error messages as "Red"

Comment: @BrianDietrich did you tried the solution? Do you still need any further assistnace on this?

Comment: Thanks Farid. I think there is a time difference here. Let me try your solution

Comment: Hello @BrianDietrich did you tried the solution? Was the problem resolved?

Comment: Farid, see my solution. With the help of codementor.io, we figured it out. Basically, if the model was invalid I was redirecting to a different route which cleared the cache. The model state is held in the session, i.e., temporarily. <code> return Page(); <--return page, don't redirect to Create, or the action </code>

Answer (score 1):

> But in the case below, I cannot trigger the client-side error messages. I.e., I can't seem to trigger the asp-for helpers against my Category model and hence?

After debugging on your issue, it seems that your `ModelState` validation `sub-key` is not getting mactched while your validation request is sending to the server and got the response from `ModelState.IsValid` from  your `OnPost` method.

**How to fix it:**

It seems that your `model` location path is something like `AbbyTrain.Pages.Categories.CreateModel` so here the problem begins. It cannot match the `validation sub key` with `Category.Name`. I think it's not same with the `validation sub key`. Please check it within your environment.

Here is the working demo for you:

**Model:**

```
public class Category
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    }
```

**View:**

```
@model DotNet6MVCWebApp.Models.Category
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">
<form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="OnPost" method="post">
    
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4"> 
        <div class="row pb-2"> 
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Create New Category</h2> 
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="CategoryName"></label>        
            <input asp-for="CategoryName" class="form-control"/>       
            <span asp-validation-for="CategoryName" class="text-danger"></span> 
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DisplayOrder"></label>
            <input asp-for="DisplayOrder" class="form-control"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="DisplayOrder" class="text-danger"></span>        
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DateCreated"></label> 
            <input  name="DateCreated" type="date" class="form-control bg-info"/>
            <span asp-validation-for="DateCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        
        <button type="submit" class="bnt btn-primary" style="width: 150px;">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

**Note:** Make sure your `validation sub key` is same as your `asp-validation-for`. You could check that on `debug mode` under `results View` as the below screenshot.

[image]

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(Category category)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _db.Categories.AddAsync(category);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Debugging Steps:**

[image]

> How can I debug the model? Or look at how it is using the data annotations?

1. Check the inspect element on your UI code.
2. Make sure `data-valmsg-for` and `name` or `id` attributes are matched properly.
3. See the below screen capture for details steps

[image]

**Note:**

Make sure you have `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` on your `shared` folder and it should contains following references:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

You could refer to [our official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#client-side-validation) for more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#client-side-validation).

Comment: Farid, thank you for your assistance. You spent quite a bit of time on your answer.  As far as making sure the subkey in the debugger matches the asp-for-validation name, my model (as you can see if you refer back to my code) the Category model is Name your model has CategoryName and when I leave Name on the create page blank, yes it shows in the debugger as invalid. If I place something in the Category.Name field, then the debugger shows as valid.

Comment: I still can't get the client-side default error messages to trigger; default meaning, Category.Name is required and Display.Order can't be ' '.  In the Youtube video, Patel's code does trigger client-side errors. I am moving on to finish the video. I want to see if any other folk have had this issue.

Comment: How can I debug the model? Or look at how it is using the data annotations?

Comment: I have added another GIF capture for you you can take a look. I hope that would show the steps accordingly.

Comment: In addition, if the given answer was helpful you can accept the answer . You can do that by right clicking on left check mark beside your question [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow) Or you can check here [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of codementor.io, we figured out that when there is an error on the page and your server is catching the error, your ModelState is sent back to the client as Invalid. If you redirect to an action, you are destroying this cache. IN this case, redirecting to Create.cshtml cleared the session in memory. Just redirect to the Page, then you will see the server errors.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if(Category.Name == Category.DisplayOrder.ToString())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Category.Name", "Category name cannot be the same as category display order");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _db.Category.AddAsync(Category); //the BindProperties attribute above takes care of this--not having to pass category Category, just use a capital C to bind it to the Category model
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("Index");
            }
            else
                //2022-05-19, Problems were occurring on the error messages returned and displayed (i.e., they were not) from the server. 
                //
                //Resolved on codementor.io: When ModelState.Isvalid returns false,
                //you do not need to redirect to Create.cshtml, ***because the state of the model will be lost, because model state is stored
                //in memory cache, i.e. by session; rather you just return the page (ie return Page())

                return Page(); <--return page, don't redirect to Create, or the action
                
        }
```

Comment: Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Comment: No, thank you Farid, you have been very helpful.